# Open a new modal in the modal and close the previous one

Tags: reactjs, sockets, events, bootstrap-modal

In my react project, i have following content in my App.js:

**Eg:**

```
<GameStats />
<UserStats />
```

**UserStats.js** and **GameStats.js** will be open when my socket have data.

In the **GameStats.js** modal, there are user list and when click on user name, then **UserStats.js** Modal will be open.
Now i want to know, how can close **GameStats.js modal** when **UserStats.js modal will be open** ? i cant use setState, because components is deffrent.

is there a way to do this with redux ?

**Here is my example code:**

GameStats.js:

```
class GameStats extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      show: false
    };
    this.handleShow = this.handleShow.bind(this);
    this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
  }
  handleShow() {
      this.setState({ show: true });
  }
  handleClose() {
      this.setState({ show: false});
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    Socket.on("message", data => this.example(data));
  }
  handleInfo() {
    //Send Request to Socket. then the response will be open in UserStats.js modal
    //socket.emit('userInfo', 1);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Modal
          size="lg"
          show={this.handleShow}
          onHide={this.handleClose}
          aria-labelledby="st-lg-modal"
        >
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title id="st-lg-modal">GameStats</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            <a href="#" onclick={() => this.handleInfo()}>
              Leon
            </a>
          </Modal.Body>
        </Modal>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

UserStats.js:

```
class UserStats extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      show: false
    };
    this.handleShow = this.handleShow.bind(this);
    this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
  }
  handleShow() {
      this.setState({ show: true });
  }
  handleClose() {
      this.setState({ show: false});
  }
componentDidMount() {
    socket.on("userInfo", data => this.example(data));
}
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Modal
          size="lg"
          show={this.handleShow}
          onHide={this.handleClose}
          aria-labelledby="st-lg-modal"
        >
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title id="st-lg-modal">UserStats</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
                  Contents
          </Modal.Body>
        </Modal>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Also, this is my **index.js** content:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <div>
                         <UserStats />
                         <GameStats />
                        <Route exact path="/" component={Game} />
                </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Please Read Again, i edit content.

Comment: Please share your code, how you are getting it open?

Comment: i share my code in post.

Comment: Please also share the parent component in which you are rendering the <GameStats />
and <UserStats /> component. Looks like you will need to handle the handleShow state outside (in parent component)

Comment: @MuhammadHaseeb 


i edit first post.

Comment: @MuhammadHaseeb These components have no parent.